# How to remove elements from a vector by order of priority

Tags: java, vector, priority-queue, distributed-system

I have a Vector that stores a String Host and an int Port Number of a node.

Is there any way I can remove higher priority values from this vector first, for example, any nodes with port numbers starting with 8?

Node and Port are recieved from a bufferedreader

```
in = s.getInputStream();
bin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

request[NODE] = bin.readLine();
request[PORT] = bin.readLine();

buffer.saveRequest(request);
```

Buffer Class
And Stored Using this SaveRequest method

```
private Vector<Object> data = new Vector<Object>();
public synchronized void saveRequest (String[] r){

    data.add(r[0]);
    data.add(r[1]);    

}
```

This is my current get method which only returns values in FIFO order

```
synchronized public Object  get(){
    Object o = null; 

    if (data.size() > 0){
        o = data.get(0);
        data.remove(0);
    }
    return o;
}
```

The Node and Port is defined in the arguments of the Node Class but a typical data entry would be "127.0.0.1" "8001"

Comment: you can use a comparator to sort the data. Please share the data structure of the data list and data added to the list.

Comment: Have added in the extra data you suggested.